# converting shp file to geojson

Tags: google-maps, geojson, qgis

I used QGIS to convert a .shp file into this .geojson file:
http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/test2/js/munis.geojson

But when I use this code to place the information on a google map, nothing happens:

```
    var map;
    var myOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.4417, -80.0000),
          zoom: 12,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);
   map.data.loadGeoJson('js/munis.geojson');
```

What did I do wrong?

See demo: http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/test2/test.html

Comment: Looks like your coordinates are in meters, you need to perform the conversion that Google Maps is expecting. See related answer at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61096/how-to-get-correct-format-of-coordinates-for-export-to-geojson-from-qgis

Comment: @snkashis: Thanks! That helped!

Answer (score 1):

When saving the layer as a .geojson in QGIS (really when saving any layer in QGIS), you can choose the coordinate system of the saved layer.  This is one of the reasons why use QGIS more than ArcGIS.